# how to get response of clicked captcha as a variable

Tags: php, ajax, recaptcha

I want to include google recaptcha in my login page.

Normally, I collect variables from various inputs and sent them using `ajax` to `prologin.php` for proccessing.

But don't know how to get response of `clicked` captcha, what kind of responses are possible (`true`, `false`, or... what ?), to proccess them also.

**login.php**

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<input type='text'...>
<input type='checkbox'...>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld..."></div>
<div id='btnlogin'>LOGIN</div>
```

**login.js**

```
$('#btnlogin').click(function(){
var a = ...;
var b = ...;
var captchaResponse = ...;  // what ?
$.ajax({
    url: 'prologin.php',
    ...
});
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you using reCaptcha V1 or V2?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul V2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `grecaptcha.getResponse()` to get the user's response. And as a sidenote, use `grecaptcha.reset()` to ask the end user to verify with reCAPTCHA again.

```
$('#btnlogin').click(function(){
    var a = ...;
    var b = ...;
    var captchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'prologin.php',
        ...
    });
    ...
});
```

Here's the reference: [**https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify**](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

#### Update(1):

Yes, you have to send user's response to backend PHP page *prologin.php* and get it verified there. So roughly, your AJAX and backend PHP code would be like this:

**AJAX:**

```
$('#btnlogin').click(function(){
    var a = ...;
    var b = ...;
    var captchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'prologin.php',
        data: {a: a, b: b, captchaResponse: captchaResponse};
        success: function(data) {
            // reset the reCaptcha
            grecaptcha.reset();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // error
        }
    });
    ...
});
```

**prologin.php**

```
<?php
    //your site secret key
    $secret = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY';

    if(isset($_POST['captchaResponse']) && !empty($_POST['captchaResponse'])){
        //get verified response data
        $param = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$_POST['captchaResponse'];
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents($param);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

        if($responseData->success){
            // success
        }else{
            // failure
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks Rajdeep. If I understand right the whole story, I also need an aditional verification the given string with google ?

Comment: @bonaca I've updated my answer. Please see the **Update(1)** section of my answer.

Comment: You're a real `Raj`. I'll try. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Google recaptcha's response is sent with name `g-recaptcha-response`. This is also class name and ID for an input (textarea). So you can try any of these:

```
$('#g-recaptcha-response').val();
$('form .g-recaptcha-response').val();
$('form [name="g-recaptcha-response"]').val();
```

Comment: `var captcha = $('#g-recaptcha-response').val(); console.log(captcha);` gives me a very long string, and empty string if captcha is not clicked. What about if captcha is clicked but not passed, if it suspects for bot, for example ? I cannot produce that scenario.

Comment: Then it will maybe returns empty string too (cannot reproduce it now), or maybe a string, but still you have to verify it on the server-side and google will know if that response is valid or not. Just verify that string like without ajax.

Comment: I forget: I clicked on the recaptcha, passed and then waited few seconds to get message that timeout gone, then checked and input was changed to an empty string.

Comment: thanks a lot. what do you mean - `but still you have to verify it on the server-side and google will know if that response is valid or not`? What kind of additional verification ? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry, i have been offline for a while. But as you see in the accepted answer that verification is in the **prologin.php**.